# Python "in operator" with Multiple Arguments

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I've got a simple python question. First, see the code.

```
l1 = ['one', ['1', '2']]

for item1, item2 in l1:
    print (item1)
    for subitem in item2:
        print (subitem)
```

I assumed that this would print 'one' then '1' '2', but I receive the error:

```
    for item1, item2 in l1:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

There's some code in the tutorial that I'm following (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter9/) that leads me to believe that what I'm trying to do (the multiple args with the in statement) is possible - but what is the logic here?

Comment: in first loop you do `item1, item2 = "one"` so you get error

Answer (score 2):

Your outer loop shouldn't be a loop:

```
item1, item2 = l1
print(item1)
for subitem in item2:
    print(subitem)
```

A loop like `for item1, item2 in l1` expects each element of `l1` to unpack into two items separately. For example, if `l1` were `[(1, 2), (3, 4), ...]`, then the first iteration would set `item1, item2 = 1, 2`, and the second iteration would set `item1, item2 = 3, 4`, and so on.